# How to create a Matrix with values having column name and row name?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

Here is a reproducible code

```
A <- matrix(sample(1:12,12,T),ncol=4)
rownames(A) <- letters[1:3]
colnames(A) <- letters[11:14]
```

The matrix now looks like

```
   k  l m  n
a  9 12 5 12
b 10  9 3  2
c 11 11 9  7
```

I want my matrix should look something like this

```
   k                       l                        m                 n
a row a column k value 9   12                       5                12
b row b column k value 10   9                       3                 2
c row c column k value 11  11                       9                 7
```

Similarly with other values in matrix( I am not writing coz it becomes messy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner. All vectorized, no loops needed.

```
matrix(sprintf("row %s column %s value %s",
               rownames(A)[row(A)],
               colnames(A)[col(A)], A),
       nrow = nrow(A))

#      [,1]                      [,2]                      [,3]                    
# [1,] "row a column k value 12" "row a column l value 10" "row a column m value 5"
# [2,] "row b column k value 5"  "row b column l value 7"  "row b column m value 6"
# [3,] "row c column k value 10" "row c column l value 9"  "row c column m value 7"
#      [,4]                     
# [1,] "row a column n value 12"
# [2,] "row b column n value 2" 
# [3,] "row c column n value 9"
```

Use `set.seed(47)` with `A <- matrix(sample(1:12,12,T),ncol=4)` to replicate results.

Comment: This is good. Could also be written as `A[] <- sprintf("row %s column %s value %s", rownames(A)[row(A)], colnames(A)[col(A)], A)` to entirely meet OP's expectations.

Comment: Little shorter, but I like the option of not necessarily overwriting the original, regardless of OP's phrasing. They can always do `A <-` if they want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to get what you want:

```
  for (i in 1:nrow(A)){
   for (j in 1:ncol(A)){
    A[i,j]<- paste("row ",rownames(A)[i]," column ",colnames(A)[j]," value ", A[i,j], sep="")
   }
  }
```

Comment: This does not give the desired output.

Comment: If you replace `i` and `j` in the loop with `rownames(A)[i]` and `colnames(A)[j]` this will work

Comment: @Gregor I edited my answer based on your suggestion.  thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using two `for` loops. Thanks to @Gregor.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(A)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(A))
   A[i, j] <- 
    paste("row", rownames(A)[i], "column", colnames(A)[j], "value", A[i, j])
}
A
#  k                        l                         m                         n                       
#a "row a column k value 4" "row a column l value 11" "row a column m value 12" "row a column n value 1"
#b "row b column k value 5" "row b column l value 3"  "row b column m value 8"  "row b column n value 3"
#c "row c column k value 7" "row c column l value 11" "row c column m value 8"  "row c column n value 3"
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1)
A <- matrix(sample(1:12,12,T),ncol=4)
rownames(A) <- letters[1:3]
colnames(A) <- letters[11:14]
```

Comment: I think `rownames(A)[i]` will work more simply than `rownames(A[i, , drop = FALSE])` (and similarly for the `colnames`).

Answer (score 0):

Try `as.data.frame.table` and then just paste names.

```
x <- as.data.frame( as.table(A))
x
   Var1 Var2 Freq
1     a    k    2
2     b    k   10
3     c    k   12
4     a    l    5
5     b    l    4
6     c    l   11
7     a    m    4
8     b    m    8
9     c    m    8
10    a    n    5
11    b    n    5
12    c    n    6
y <- apply(x, 1, function(y) paste(c("row", "column", "value"), y, collapse=" "))
matrix(y, nrow =3, dimnames = dimnames(A))
k                         l                         m                         n                        
a "row a column k value  2" "row a column l value  5" "row a column m value  4" "row a column n value  5"
b "row b column k value 10" "row b column l value  4" "row b column m value  8" "row b column n value  5"
c "row c column k value 12" "row c column l value 11" "row c column m value  8" "row c column n value  6"
```

Answer (score 0):

A matrix must have values all of the same data type.  So, first convert to dataframe using `as.data.frame()`.  Then use `paste()` to create your concatenated string and update column k in your newly created dataframe.

```
B <- as.data.frame(A)
B$k <- paste('row', rownames(B), 'column k value', B$k)
B

#                        k  l m  n
# a row a column k value 8 11 8  2
# b row b column k value 7 12 7  2
# c row c column k value 6  6 2 12
```

Comment: OP wants the whole matrix that way, not just one column. (Last line of the question is *"Similarly with other values in matrix( I am not writing coz it becomes messy)"*